# When I try to populate a combo box it doesn't populate

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Earlier I was able to populate a combo box depending on what another combo box has selected, I then continued on with writing code, and I come back to test it again, and it no longer populates that list, it does with another list, but one of them doesn't. So it populates the drink's, but not the main. I'm not sure what's gone on for this to happen, it all seems okay to me.

```
Public Shared cmbCatDrinks As String = "Drinks"
Public Shared cmbCatMain As String = "Main"
Public Shared cmbCatBlank As String = ""
Public Shared cmbItemBlank As String = ""

Private Sub frmRestaurantOrd_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmbCat.Items.Add(cmbCatBlank)
    cmbCat.Items.Add(cmbCatDrinks)
    cmbCat.Items.Add(cmbCatMain)
End Sub

Private Sub cmbCat_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbCat.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmbCat.SelectedItem = "Drinks" Then
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Water")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Orange Juice")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Coca Cola")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Beer")
        cmbSize.Items.Clear()
    ElseIf cmbCat.SelectedItem = "Main" Then
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Cheese and Tomato")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Ham and Pineapple")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Vegetarian")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Meat Feast")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Seafood")
        cmbSize.Items.Add("Small")
        cmbSize.Items.Add("Medium")
        cmbSize.Items.Add("Large")
        cmbItem.Items.Clear()
    Else cmbCat.SelectedItem = cmbCatBlank
        cmbItem.Items.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing the items you just added to `cmbItem` when "Main" is selected.

```
ElseIf cmbCat.SelectedItem = "Main" Then
    cmbItem.Items.Add("Cheese and Tomato")
    cmbItem.Items.Add("Ham and Pineapple")
    cmbItem.Items.Add("Vegetarian")
    cmbItem.Items.Add("Meat Feast")
    cmbItem.Items.Add("Seafood")
    cmbSize.Items.Add("Small")
    cmbSize.Items.Add("Medium")
    cmbSize.Items.Add("Large")
    cmbItem.Items.Clear() ' <-- this is clearing all the items you just added.
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't clocked that. I'm also trying to get it to clear the current selected item that is in the combo box, I set it so that when i select the blank selection in combo box, it clears the other combo box, but it doesn't clear the text that's been selected if that makes sense?

Comment: @Ollie4735 Set `cmbItem.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

Comment: I found another way to do what I needed it was cmbItem.ResetText()